# AWS CloudFormation CodePipeline, ParameterOverrides, pass list to a nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameter-passing, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

The scope of the question:

AWS CodeBuild, ParametersOverrides section

[Using Parameter Override Functions with CodePipeline Pipelines](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html)

1) I can pass a string to ParameterOverrides, 
   and then pass them to a nested stack, as it is described below

-create a string parameter

-pass it to ParameterOverrides section of the AWS CodeBuild project

-parse parameter in the nested stack

Quoting the official documentation:
[AWS::CloudFormation::Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#aws-properties-stack-prop)

> If you use the Ref function to pass a parameter value to a nested
>   stack, comma-delimited list parameters must be of type String. In
>   other words, you cannot pass values that are of type
>   CommaDelimitedList to nested stacks.

2) I can not figure out on how to transform a List to a string 
   inside a ParameterOverrides section with the configuration below:

-define a Parameter with type of list 
  ServiceSubnets:
    Type: List
    Description: Subnets associated with the service

-try to pass a parameter inside ParameterOverrides section as a value
 to a nested stack, apply Join function to transform it to a string

> ```
>            ParameterOverrides: !Sub |
>               {
>                 "ImageURI" : { "Fn::GetParam" : [ "BuildOutput", "imageDetail.json", "ImageURI" ] },
>                 "ApplicationRepoName": "${ApplicationRepoName}",
>                 "Cluster": "${Cluster}",
>                 "ListenerArn": "${ListenerArn}",
>                 "TargetGroup": "${TargetGroup}",
>                 "ServiceDesiredCount": "${ServiceDesiredCount}",
>                 "ServiceLoadBalancerPath": "${ServiceLoadBalancerPath}",
>                 "ServiceContainerPort": "${ServiceContainerPort}",
>                 "ServiceSecurityGroups": { "Fn::Join" : [ ",", "${ServiceSecurityGroups}"] ] },
>                 "ServiceSubnets": { "Fn::Join" : [ ",", "${ServiceSubnets}" ] },
>                 "TaskContainerPort": "${TaskContainerPort}",
>                 "TaskCpu": "${TaskCpu}",
>                 "TaskMemory": "${TaskMemory}",
>                 "TaskExecutionRoleArn": "${TaskExecutionRoleArn}"
>               }
> ```

So I expect that the List should be transformed to a String and String
should be passed and then used in the nested stack, however,
attempt to deploy such stack returned an error:

> Template error: variable ServiceSecurityGroups in Fn::Sub expression
>   does not resolve to a string

My question:

Is it possible to use Join function inside ParameterOverrides section
to transform a List to a String?

If yes, I would much appreciate if you share
with me some example that illustrates how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can we pass a complete JSON file into ParameterOverrides?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot use intrinsic functions within the Fn::Sub
[Syntax Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

You can still use other intrinsic functions such as Fn::Join within Fn::Sub variable map. So your ParameterOverrides will be as follows instead:

```
ParameterOverrides: !Sub 
  - |
    {
      "ImageURI" : { "Fn::GetParam" : [ "BuildOutput", "imageDetail.json", "ImageURI" ] },
      "ApplicationRepoName": "${ApplicationRepoName}",
      "Cluster": "${Cluster}",
      "ListenerArn": "${ListenerArn}",
      "TargetGroup": "${TargetGroup}",
      "ServiceDesiredCount": "${ServiceDesiredCount}",
      "ServiceLoadBalancerPath": "${ServiceLoadBalancerPath}",
      "ServiceContainerPort": "${ServiceContainerPort}",
      "ServiceSecurityGroups": "${KEY_NAME_1}",
      "ServiceSubnets": "${KEY_NAME_2}",
      "TaskContainerPort": "${TaskContainerPort}",
      "TaskCpu": "${TaskCpu}",
      "TaskMemory": "${TaskMemory}",
      "TaskExecutionRoleArn": "${TaskExecutionRoleArn}"
    }
 - KEY_NAME_1: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref ServiceSecurityGroups ] ]
   KEY_NAME_2: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref ServiceSubnets ] ]
```

If your ServiceSecurityGroups and ServiceSubnets are already lists then remove the square braces around the !Ref statements.

Comment: Can we pass a complete JSON file into ParameterOverrides?